# How to duplicate form div in Angular with Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, clone

I am trying to clone form in angular but there's "Object is possibly 'null".
HTML:

```
<div class="form-container">
      <form class="example">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
          <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="emailFormControl" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"
                 >
          <mat-error *ngIf="nameFormControl.hasError('name') && !nameFormControl.hasError('required')">
            Please enter a valid name
          </mat-error>
          <mat-error *ngIf="nameFormControl.hasError('required')">
            Please enter name
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
          <button mat-icon-button color="primary" class="delete" matTooltip="Remove item">
            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
          </button>
      </form>
      <button id="addEmailField" (click)="clone()">
        <mat-icon>add</mat-icon> Add new item
      </button>
    </div>
```

TS:

```
 clone() {
const example = document.querySelector('.example');
const clone = example.cloneNode(true);
document.querySelector('.form-container').appendChild(clone);
```

}

I would like to copy form container. Maybe theres another better way than mine.

Comment: Manipulating DOM directly and ignoring all the Angular methods is pure nightmare and goes against the framework ideology. There is many ways you can create multiple form instances, i.e. creating component that holds the form and displaying it conditionally with structural directives like *ngFor and *ngIf. Just read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the null check operator (the ? before the dot) - this equates to an existance check - eg a?.doStuff() will compile to ...if(a){a.doStuff()}...

```
const example = document.querySelector('.example');
const clone = example?.cloneNode(true);
document.querySelector('.form-container')?.appendChild(clone);
```

or a more verbose approach

```
const example = document.querySelector('.example');
if(example) {
   const clone = example.cloneNode(true);
  const container = document.querySelector('.form-container');
  if(container){
    container.appendChild(clone);
  }
}
```